# How to make selected items in repeater bold

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I'm having a bit of trouble finding out how to make selected items in an ASP.NET Repeater control bold.

Essentially what I want to do is to highlight people from a certain State. The page has a query string (in this case the value returned is "WA"), I'm hoping that wherever the state appears, the appropriate value will be bold, leaving the others normal. So if a WA person in 2008 came second, it would be bold, then if a driver from NSW came second in 2009 it wouldn't be bold.

I have looked through the forums and Google and have found how to highlight rows, but not values / cells in repeaters.

Below is my HTML. The codebehind at the moment is quite simple and just returns the names and states. I'm assuming something will have to be done in the Databinder?

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAustChampions" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="DataTableHeading">
                <div class="DataTableCellSeason"><strong>Season</strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><strong>Champion</strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><strong>Runner Up</strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><strong>3rd</strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><strong>Track</strong></div>
            </div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <div class="DataTableCellSeason"><strong><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Season")%></strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "First")%></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Second")%></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Third")%></strong></div>
                <div class="DataTableCell"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Track")%></div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind

```
    If Not Request.QueryString("State") = Nothing Then
        Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(MSSQL.cRemoteConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Aust_Champions] WHERE (([FirstState] = '" & Request.QueryString("State") & "') OR ([SecondState] = '" & Request.QueryString("State") & "') OR ([ThirdState] = '" & Request.QueryString("State") & "')) ORDER BY [Season] DESC", cnn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        cmd.Fill(ds, "Aust_Champions")

        rptAustChampions.DataSource = ds.Tables("Aust_Champions")
        rptAustChampions.DataBind()
        cnn.Close()
    End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is there any reasons not to use ListView?

Comment: You're wide open to sql injection.

Comment: I went with a repeater as that is what i have used for similar things before, havent used listviws but if thats the way to go ill look into it. As for the SQL injection, havent done a whole lot with that yet. Focussing on getting the data right first (its a bit backwards but the clients wants to see things on the screen first)

Answer (score 0):

Even if repeater is fully customizable in terms of produced html layout, I would recommend you to switch to ListView control as it gives you much more options and most of the things you might want to do are reached easily with the listview.

Also Consider Adding SqlDataSource on your page and use QueryStringParameter. Bind you ListView to SqlDataSource. This way asp.net will take care of security when using query string parameters.

Also this is IMHO but:

There is of course strong opinion ( with a lot of reasons for it ) not to use html tables. However when you have table level data you are strongly encouraged to use html tables as they are designed exactly for that.

So if rendering your data with tables is just fine, switch to GridView. In the easiest case use BoundField and use [ItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

In case tables are out of question use listview. Use css classes for your tags in order to style individual cells.

As for repeater, you already has your layout done, so in order to add conditional styling for each cell you will change this:

```
 <div class="DataTableCell"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Track")%></div>
```

to something like this:

```
 <div class='DataTableCell <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Season") == 1 ? "MyFirstClass" : "MySecondClass"%>'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Track")%></div>
```

And define corresponding css classess in your stylesheet.

You might also want not to inline this logic and define page method that would accept your data item and return string with the name of the class:

```
  <div class='DataTableCell <%# GetCellClass(Container.DataItem) %>'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Track")%></div>
```

And in code behind:

```
 string GetCellClass( object di)  {
    var  dataItem = di as (MyDataClass);

    if (dataItem.SomeProperty == "SomeValue") return "my-css-class";

    return string.Empty;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have used HTMl tables for some things but get frustrated with them as they wont size properly. The only way I could get the items to show was use Divs and use the Table-cell CSS attribute. However I have no problem in using them providing they would as they should (things like adjusting column widths etc were a huge pain!). I will look into a ListView.